# How do I get CardView size in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I have fix size card views in a list. I would like to show in each card view a different image. I download the image from a service that I wrote. My image service allows getting the image width and height and it knows to crop the image in the middle and return it in the needed size.

How can I get the size in pixels of a card view so I could best fit to it an image?

Comment: Sorry, explain me something. You want to get the size of the `CardView` after you loaded the `ImageView` within or before you load it?. I'm a little bit confused because you said that your `CardView` has fixed size, so why can you just simply take it from the dimens?

Comment: I want to take it before loading an image. Of course I could do it only once for all cards, but it cannot be set in advance since each device has different screen size.

Comment: Please consider adding some of your code to the question, because it's hard to understand what answer you are looking for.

Comment: I have no idea why this question is off topic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is to get the size of the view, just use `view.getWidth()` and `view.getHeight()`.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed. Frankly, I could have guessed it easily... :)